# Add XML after specific node

Tags: xml, linq, powershell

I have the following XML document already loaded as an XElement (`$el`):

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <e></e>
</a>
```

How can I use PowerShell to append another XElement (`$theElement`) beneath `<c></c>`? I tried the following:

```
$where = {
    param ($item)
    return ($item.Name.LocalName -eq "c")
}

$el.Descendants().Where($where).FirstOrDefault().Add($theElement)
```

but this errors out:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject,System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]] does not contain a method named 'FirstOrDefault'.

Note: `$el` and `$theElement` has to be `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that PowerShell is rather stuck in the .Net 1.1 dark ages.

- There are no extension methods. Nothing in Linq works the easy way, you have to call them as static methods.
- XmlDocument is first class, (XDocument is not -- why bother, since extension methods don't work)

`FirstOrDefault` is an extension method, so it's simply not there in PowerShell, you'd have to call `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::FirstOrDefault(`... and the `Where` method isn't the one from Linq, it's a PowerShell specific addition, so you need to use it to do the `First` thing.

### TL;DR

You need to write something like this (the `[0]` is because when you tell `Where` to return only one item, it returns an array of one item):

```
$el.Descendants.Where({ $_.Name.LocalName -eq "c" }, 1)[0].Add($theElement)
```

#### The normal PowerShell way is to use XmlDocument and XPath instead:

Given `$xml` and `$node` and the XPath selector:

```
[xml]$xml = "
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <e></e>
</a>
"

$node = "<k/>"

$selector = "//c"
```

You can use the Xml module from the PowerShellGallery:

```
# Insert <k> after <c> in the $xml XmlDocument
$xml | Update-Xml -After //c $node
```

Or you can write it by hand:

```
# Make node an actual xmlElement, and ensure
# Convert the element to be part of our output document
$node = $xml.ImportNode( ([Xml]$node).DocumentElement, $true )

# Select the node to insert after
$target = $xml.SelectSingleNode($selector)

# Actually insert it
$null = $target.ParentNode.InsertAfter($node, $target)
```